# How to create a sub menu with custom post types?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, submenu

I built a website with WordPress and I have custom posts types.
In some pages I have the subnavigation and I want to show it in the page like in the follow image:

http://www.andreavisibelli.com/screen-1.jpg

it works fine, isn't it?

Yes but if you try to see "Vini" page as in the follow image you can't see the sub-menu:

http://www.andreavisibelli.com/screen-2.jpg

The difference between the two submenus is that the first is filled of base pages of WordPress while the second is filled of custom post pages!

MY CODE IS:

```
  <ul id="subnavigation">
<?php
  if($post->post_parent)
  $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0");
  else
  $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0");
  if ($children) { ?>
  <ul>
  <?php echo $children; ?>
  </ul>
  <?php } ?>
  </ul>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in [WordPress Documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/):

> #### [Function Reference/wp list pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages)
>
> **Usage**:
> `<?php wp_list_pages( $args ); ?>`
>
> **Default usage**:
>
> ```
> <?php $args = array(
>   'depth'        => 0,
>   'show_date'    => '',
>   'date_format'  => get_option('date_format'),
>   'child_of'     => 0,
>   'exclude'      => '',
>   'include'      => '',
>   'title_li'     => __('Pages'),
>   'echo'         => 1,
>   'authors'      => '',
>   'sort_column'  => 'menu_order, post_title',
>   'link_before'  => '',
>   'link_after'   => '',
>   'walker'       => '',
>   'post_type'    => 'page',
>   'post_status'  => 'publish' 
> ); ?>
> ```

As you can see, the parameter **`post_type`** is the one you need to achieve a Custom Post Type listing. Simply use your CPT slug.